# Getting data from database to textbox?

Tags: c#

i have this code, but it doesn't work

```
try
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select nev, telefonszam, felhasznalonev, lakcim,email from Felhasznalo where felhasznalonev='"+cbUsername.Text+"' ", con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string name = reader.GetString(0); 
                        string phone = reader.GetInt32(1).ToString();  
                        string username = reader.GetString(2);
                        string address = reader.GetString(3);
                        string email = reader.GetString(4);  

                        tbUsername.Text = username;
                        tbName.Text = name;
                        //tbPhoneNumber.Text = phoneNumber.ToString();
                        tbAddress.Text = address;
                        tbEmail.Text = email;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

the error is: **Specified cast is not valid.**
What is wrong?
i got the solution from here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKealDA-Wr8

Comment: Instead of trying to call reader.GetString()` why don't you fully qualify the column names that you are returning.. the error is probably a datatype issue in regards to your calling the GetString do you have any date fields or Integer fields..?? also change ` MessageBox.Show(""+ex);` to be  `MessageBox.Show(" " + ex.Message);` It also appears that you have not used the debugger to step thru the code.. what line does the error happen on...?

Comment: the phone is LONG in database, but there isn't getLong

Comment: ok like I was suggesting you should change this to match the column names ...anyway you need to cast the value correctly..
try this `string phone = (sring)reader.GetInt32(1);` or use the `Convert.ToString()` method also what happens when you try this 
`string phone = (string)reader["telefonszam"];`

Comment: and what should i do if the phone is bigInt in database?

Comment: doesn't matter if it's a long.. you should use some other way to get the value don't rely on just one way of doing things ..this is where Casting comes into play doesn't Matter... you are only selecting.. you are not updating.. now if you are updating then you need to change the datatype of that column so for example here in USA we normally define phone numbers as `VarChar` because of the many different formats of how phone numbers are formatted in this country does that make since..?

Comment: `string phone = (string)reader["telefonszam"].ToString();` this works thanks

Comment: then Mark the Answer I have provided as the acceptable answer. thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would suggest that you do this for all the fields that you are returning.

```
string phone = (string)reader["telefonszam"].ToString();
```

What if the Database structure changes or you add new columns and change the index / order.. using GetString(4) for example would be fail if the datatype in that column position were to change that is why I recommended that you use the actual column names.